# Hi I'm trying to write a sql alchemy query but it gives me the error "cant determine which from clause to join from"

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

So I have a sql query which joins table and fetches data

```
select "FileSets"."Id", "SetFile"."Alias" from "Feeds"
join "FeedSnapshots" on "Feeds"."ActiveSnapshotId"="FeedSnapshots"."Id"
join "Subscriptions" on "Feeds"."Id" = "Subscriptions"."FeedId"
join "SubscriptionSnapshots" on "Subscriptions"."ActiveSnapshotId"="SubscriptionSnapshots"."Id"
join "FileSets" on "SubscriptionSnapshots"."Id"="FileSets"."SubscriptionSnapshotId"
join "SetFile" on "FileSets"."Id"="SetFile"."FileSetId" where "Feeds"."Id"=398 and "Expected"=true
```

Now I'm trying to convert this to a sqlAlchemy query but it gives me the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't determine which FROM clause to join from, there are multiple FROMS which can join to this entity. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explcit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.
```

My sqlAlchemy query looks like this:

```
db.session.query(FileSet.id, SetFile.alias).join(FeedSnapshot, Feed.active_snapshot_id == FeedSnapshot.id) \
        .join(Subscription, Feed.id == Subscription.feed_id).join(SubscriptionSnapshot, Subscription.active_snapshot_id == SubscriptionSnapshot.id) \
        .join(FileSet, SubscriptionSnapshot.id == FileSet.subscription_snapshot_id).join(SetFile, FileSet.id == SetFile.file_set_id) \
        .filter(and_(SetFile.expected, Feed.id == orig_feed_snapshot.feed_id)).all()
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my SqlAlchemy query?

Comment: I think you could use [```select_from(table)```](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.select_from)

Comment: Thanks, that worked

Comment: I like that. I advise you to test the other variant as well. It could be more helpful as the application development continues.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you want to, you can also use one with flask_sqlalchemy instead of the pure sqlalchemy request.

The following query should work.

```
id_alias_pairs = Feed.query\
  .join(FeedSnapshot, Feed.active_snapshot_id == FeedSnapshot.id)\
  .join(Subscription, Feed.id == Subscription.feed_id)\
  .join(SubscriptionSnapshot, Subscription.active_snapshot_id == SubscriptionSnapshot.id)\
  .join(FileSet, SubscriptionSnapshot.id == FileSet.subscription_snapshot_id)\
  .join(SetFile, FileSet.id == SetFile.file_set_id)\
  .filter(Feed.id==1, SetFile.expected)\
  .with_entities(FileSet.id, SetFile.alias)\
  .all()

print(id_alias_pairs)
```